# How to count the number of names in a queue that begin with the same first letter?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stack, queue

I'm interested in how to count the number of names in a queue that begin with the same first character.

My program will be asking the user to input several names, and the names will be stored in a queue. However, I am required to count the number of names in the queue that begins with the same first character. How do I do that? I'm new to java so I don't know much.

> It should print the following statistics:
>   - The total number of country names in the queue that begins with the same letter.
>   - To compute the above statistics you may use other data structures, such as Array, or ArrayList/Vector.

Example:

> User inputs/what is in the queue:
>
> 1. Bob
> 2. Isabella
> 3. Sean
> 4. Suzy
> 5. Sally
> 6. Ida

Output:

> Total number of countries start with I : 2
>
> Total number of countries start with S : 3

I've tried searching around on this but I haven't really found a solid method to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you storing the names? In a List or an Array?

Comment: Have you worked out an algorithm for how to do it? If you can describe how a person should do it (i.e. not a computer program), step by step, that's a good place to start.

Comment: Is there any other way besides the map method?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = ...;// create a map which can hold key as first character and value as number of occurances of that character

for (String input : userInputs) {//iterate over the user inputs
    Integer count = map.get(input.charAt(0));
    if (count == null) count = 0;
    map.put(input.charAt(0), count + 1);//for each input insert key as first character and value as 1 if its first time else last count + 1.
}
```

Or if you are using Java 8, you could use something like:

```
userInputs.stream().forEach(input -> map.put(input.charAt(0), map.getOrDefault(input.charAt(0), 0) + 1));
```

Comment: Only there is no `getOrElse(...)` method in Java's `Map` interface. There is `getOrDefault(...)` since Java 8.

Comment: I think you mean `getOrDefault`, and that was only added in Java 8 - so both of your suggestions only apply to that.

Comment: @SMA but still both answers only apply to Java 8.

Comment: I see what you meant @AndyTurner

Comment: If you're using java 8 features, you can use `Map.compute` as well: `userInputs.stream().forEach(input -> map.compute(input.charAt(0), (c, n) -> n == null ? 1 : n+1));` (One lookup vs. 2 lookups)

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple implementation using a loop - that is if you're interrested in **one letter only**. Otherwise I reccommend the map solution.

```
    Queue<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
    //You need to fill the queue

    //The starting letter
    String ch = "a";


    int count = 0;
    for(String name : names)) {
 if (name.toLowerCase().startsWith(ch)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%d names start with %s%n", count, ch);
```

Comment: Why not just `String ch = "a"`? It's already lowercase, and no need to repeatedly build string. Also, the output shows that multiple starting letters are needed.

Comment: "Begin with the same first character". So save assumption is: Input is a char, not a String. But yes, having a String in the first place would make things easier. But this way (having it spelled out) it's better for a learner I think.

Comment: I disagree. Somebody learning Java might see `"".Character.toLowerCase(ch)` and think "somebody experienced suggested it, so that's how I should do it too". Simpler, more readable code is better.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the queue and check the first letter by splitting it into char array and if you find the matching letter then increment the particular counter.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Map<Character, Queue<String>>` for storing names and calling `m.get('I').size()` for the count...?

e.g.

```
// for adding name to map use following piece of code

Character c = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0));

if (m.containsKey(c)) {
    m.get(c).add(name)
} else {
    Queue<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
    l.add(name);
    m.put(name.charAt(0), l);
}
```

please refer Collection APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] list = {};
    int[] count = new int[26];
    for(String name : list){
        char firstChar = Character.toLowerCase(name.charAt(0));
        count[firstChar - 97]++;
        //97 is the ascii value for 'a'
    }
```

Answer by @SMA works for all the cases, if you want to avoid hashmaps,you can do something like this as well. I have considered you are ignoring case.